# While Loop with multiple conditions in PHP

Tags: php, random, while-loop

Generating a **Random number** between **`0 & 3`** in `PHP` with **`multiple conditions`**.

```
<?php
    $answer_ll = 1;
    $ll_50_rand_1 = 2;
    $ll_50_rand_2 = $answer_ll;
    while(($ll_50_rand_2 == $answer_ll) && ($ll_50_rand_2 == $ll_50_rand_1)){
    $ll_50_rand_2 = rand(0,3);
    }
echo $ll_50_rand_2;?>
```

I tried above code, but the *`randomly generated number`* is **repeating** either with `$answer_ll` or with `$ll_50_rand_1`.

> All the numbers are written just for an example, else all the numbers are dynamic. (Changeable on the situations)

**Statement View:**

I just want a random number from a specific range with a condition.
The condition will be that the randomly generated number cannot be X & Y.

X & Y are always decided when a page is loaded. It means they are dynamic

Comment: your while loop is never being executed because `ll_50_rand_2` can only match one value at a time not two

Comment: Why don't you use rand(min,max)?
echo rand(0,3);

Comment: So what's the perfect method to execute it with my needs? @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: you don't need the loop

Comment: this condition are false !!!
($ll_50_rand_2 == $ll_50_rand_1) so you never get in that loop !

Comment: What is the purpose and goal of this? - What are the conditions you're trying to define etc.

Comment: May a small edit to the question will help for better understanding

Comment: @Raja I added an answer based on your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has in your example already logical problems

you declaire:  $ll_50_rand_2 = $answer_ll;
and than have you taht condition ($ll_50_rand_2 == $answer_ll) ? realy? ^^ this is not necessary

than you fill a variable in a loop, but make the echo after, that out put only the last random number.

if I understood correctly you want to spend depending on the variable of the variable $ answer so many random numbers.

```
<?php
    $answer_ll = 3;
    $ll_50_rand_1 = 3;

    for($i = 0; $i < $answer_ll && $anser_ll == $ll_50_rand_1; $i++){
         $ll_50_rand_2 = rand(0,3);
         echo $ll_50_rand_2 . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23cbff911e01114e3711d272fde4b0c2d9d6c2c0

maybe can this example help you :)

Comment: I need only one random number and 2 conditions, you didn't add `$ll_50_rand_1`

Comment: I tried your update, but it seems it has some error, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b21c62f0db4259935533215b9c0f1a6bc47f313c (I fixed `answer` spelling, though there is an error)

Comment: try it like that ;) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec264b16ce753815865846943173634b0a781ac2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the purpose correctly, then you want a random number that cannot be X or Y.

If that is the case, then you can achieve that by doing the following

```
function random_number_with_conditions($x, $y) {
    $random_number = rand(0,3);

    if($random_number == $x || $random_number == $y)
        return random_number_with_conditions($x, $y);

    return $random_number;
}
```

This function will generate a random number, then check that random number against the conditions, if any of the conditions are equal to the randomly generated number then it will try again, and it will continue to do so until it returns a number that isn't any of the two conditions.

Comment: **NOTE:** If you want `rand()` to be `rand(0,1)` and the conditions are 0 and 1 then this function will continue endlessly until all memory is used, if you need a dynamic range then add another if-statement to check if it should be allowed to call itself.